# SSIS Package Fails with Error "must install lookup of integration services or higher"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS package from Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) and get the following error upon execution. "To run SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Lookup of Integration Services or higher". This is odd because I have other SSIS packages that execute from SSMS with no problem. I am wondering if the problem is with the account running the SQL Server Agent (Local System) or if there is something else I am missing. I am running the 32 bit runtime and have created a sample package which reads data from an excel source into a flat file. This runs fine from SSMS, when I add a lookup table to the mix though it fails with the above error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Similar unresolved issue [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9ca73adc-a9fc-4ce6-9064-658a726d0e00) where the "Lookup of" part of the error message is initially "Recordset Destination of". When the Recordset Destination is removed, the error reappears for the Lookup component.